# MVVM Binding Problems with Pivot ItemTemplates Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, templates, binding, pivot, itemssource

I have a Pivot element that has a header template and an itemtemplate with a listbox which also has a itemtemplate. The header template is bound to a list of "DOWS" which i create via code. This works fine. Each DOW has a entityset TDs and i want to bind the listbox itemtemplate to this source. Once i bound it, deleting an item updates the ui fine but adding an item doesn't update the ui.

the entityset is based off of the "Local database with mvvm" example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405(v=vs.105).aspx

I've researched for a few days and cant find anything helpful. some solutions i found where to wrap the entityset in a observable collection but that didnt seem to work. Another one was to use BindingLists, but entitySets dont have "ToBindingList()" for windows phone 7. Ive created observable collections in my ViewModel that i could bind to, but then i have no way of telling the listbox itemtemplate which collection to bind to when its created.

Any ideas?

I Can post more code if needed.

Thanks!!

Example Observablen Collections in ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<TDItem> _twoDaysAgoItems;
    public ObservableCollection<TDItem> TwoDaysAgoItems
    {
        get { return _twoDaysAgoItems; }
        set
        {

            _twoDaysAgoItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TwoDaysAgoItems");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TDItem> _yesterdayItems;
    public ObservableCollection<TDItem> YesterdayItems
    {
        get { return _yesterdayItems; }
        set
        {
            _yesterdayItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("YesterdayItems");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TDItem> _todayItems;
    public ObservableCollection<TDItem> TodayItems
    {
        get { return _todayItems; }
        set
        {

            _todayItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TodayItems");
        }
    }
```

EntitySet

```
    private EntitySet<TDItem> _tds;
    [Association(Storage = "_ts", OtherKey = "_dowId", ThisKey = "Id")]
    public EntitySet<TDItem> TDs 
    {
        get { return this._tds; 
            }

        set { 
           NotifyPropertyChanging("TDs");
            this._tds.Assign(value);
           NotifyPropertyChanged("TDs");
            }
    }

    public DOW()
    {
        _tds = new EntitySet<TDItem>(
            new Action<TDItem>(this.attach_TD), 
            new Action<TDItem>(this.detach_TD)
            );
    }
```

Pivot

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="TDPivotDisplay" SelectedIndex="2" Margin="0,-10,0,0"            Grid.Row="0" Title="TD" Foreground="White" FontWeight="light" VerticalAlignment="Top"   FontSize="29.333" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" FontFamily="{StaticResource Akzidenz    Grotesk}">
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="DOW" Foreground="{Binding Colour}" FontSize="110" FontFamily="{StaticResource Akzidenz Grotesk}" Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name = "FullDate" Foreground="{Binding Colour}" FontWeight="light" FontSize="30" FontFamily="{StaticResource Akzidenz Grotesk}"  HorizontalAlignment="center" Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="421">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding TDs}" ItemTemplate = "{StaticResource ListboxItemTemp}"  x:Name ="TDLists"  Margin="12, 0, 12, 0" Width="440"/>
                </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>

    </controls:Pivot>
```

Comment: The ItemsSource of your Pivot is not set. Are you missing some more code?

Comment: The item source for the pivot is bound through the code. I ended up using a datatemplate selector although each template only has their itemsources different, but it works. Im gonna see what else i can do.